Python textual: accessing input value
I'm trying to create a weather app with Object-Oriented Design using python and the textual library. I have an input widget set up that is intended for the user to enter a location, such as a city, and a state and/or country. Then, I was planning to access this input so that I can use it to retrieve weather data for that location. However, I cannot seem to access the input in the way that I'm wanting. Here is the code I have:
from textual.app import App, ComposeResult
from textual.widgets import Static, Input

class Location:
    def __init__(self, search_input: str) -> None:
        """
        Initialize the search_input variable.
        """
        self.__search_input = search_input

    @property
    def search_input(self) -> str:
        """
        Get the search_input property.
        """
        return self.__search_input

    @search_input.setter
    def search_input(self, newSearchInput: str) -> None:
        """
        Set the value of the search_input.
        """
        self.__search_input = newSearchInput

    def getLocation(search_input) -> list[str]:
        """
        Function to define the location.
        """
        if search_input != "":
            LOCATION = str(search_input)

            city = LOCATION
            state = ""
            country = ""
            if len(LOCATION) >= 2:
                state = LOCATION[1]
                if len (LOCATION) == 3:
                    country = LOCATION[2]
        else:
            city = "Test"
            state = ""
            country = ""

        if state == "" and country == "":
            LOCATION = [city]
        elif state != "" and country == "":
            LOCATION = [city, ", ", state]
        elif state == "" and country != "":
            LOCATION = [city, ", ", "", "", country]
        elif state != "" and country != "":
            LOCATION = [city, ", ", state, ", ", country]
        return LOCATION

class WeatherApp(App):
    """
    The main class for the weather app.
    """
    def compose(self) -> ComposeResult:
        """
        Compose the app.
        """
        input = Input(value="",placeholder="Enter a location...")
        yield input
        location = Location(Input.value)
        LOCATION = location.getLocation()
        output = Static(LOCATION[0])
        yield output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Execute the app.
    """
    app = WeatherApp()
    app.run()

With how this code is set up currently, I expected the output to be "Test". This is because I pass 'Input.value' - which is what I thought was the value of the input string - into the 'getLocation' function. Then, because the search_input value in this case would be an empty string, I figured it would set the value of the city to be "Test", therefore causing the value of 'LOCATION' to be a single-index list containing the string of "Test", which would ultimately cause the value of the output to be "Test". However, the value of the output is instead "<main.Location object at 0x7f6c2716db10>".
How can I modify my code so that the value of the input string can be correctly accessed?

Breaking it down:
        LOCATION = location.getLocation()
        output = Static(LOCATION[0])
        yield output

This is where you get the output written, and the output is the first element of LOCATION (whatever that is at this point) wrapped in Static().
LOCATION is the return value of .getLocation(), but an issue is that .getLocation is defined like this:
class Location:
    ...

    def getLocation(search_input) -> list[str]:
        ...

Since you defined it as a function inside a class definition, it is a method of that class, and expects the first parameter to be self. You can name it differently (and that's what search_input is) but it will still get assigned the object instance itself.
So, when .getLocation() starts, search_input is an instance of main.Location.
Following the logic of the function, that value ends up getting cast as a str (becoming the representation of the object) and assigned to city and city ends up at the start of the returned list.
You can add self,  to the start of the parameter list of the method, but note that you're not actually passing any search input to .getLocation(), so that will lead to the next error. How did you expect the input to end up in the call?
Another note: you're getting really creative with your naming and are ignoring a lot of best practices and style guidelines that make your code harder to read and will cause editors and IDEs to (correctly) generate warnings. Don't name regular variables in all caps like LOCATION (unless you intend for them to be globals, and even that's dubious). Don't use double underscores unless you need name mangling like you did for .__search_input. Don't mix snake_case (search_input) with camelCase getLocation - snake_case is the default for Python, and if you have very strong reasons to deviate from it (like compatibility with an existing codebase), make the choice consistently, or your code becomes nigh unreadable and very hard to maintain.
Depending on what editor or IDE you use, it should have pointed out the issue with renaming self to search_input, but you may not notice if there's style and syntax warnings blaring everywhere, which is another reason to just learn to follow PEP8.
